# Testing if one sample can be from a specific class

Tags: unsupervised-learning

Suppose I have 2 customer segments in a bank (**private class** and **another class**) defined by the institution itself. and I want to increase the amount of private clients class, bring clients from other class.How could I find similar clients with the **private class** ?

I thought of a distance approach like **Knn** to look for points close to private class customers, does anyone have another suggestion?

Comment: I am supposing that you have number of covariates measured per client, which you refer to as "points close to private customers"? A discriminant analysis may be what you need to find the variables discriminating both classes.

Comment: Sorry, private is a class where I want to increase the number of clients in it. Yes, we have profile variables, credit card consumption, amount of money in current account, and other variables....